# selenium web driver download big version of images

Tags: selenium-webdriver

some websites like [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/embedded-microcontrollers/685?k=stm32f407), for img tag has two source(small version and big version) :

```
<img itemprop="image" class="pszoomer" zoomimg="//media.digikey.com/Renders/STMicro%20Renders/497;144LQFP-1.6-20x20;144.jpg" border="0" height="64" src="//media.digikey.com/Renders/STMicro%20Renders/497;144LQFP-1.6-20x20;144_tmb.jpg" alt="STM32F407ZET6 - STMicroelectronics" title="STM32F407ZET6 - STMicroelectronics">
```

I want to download image link in **zoomimg** attribute , any suggestion ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **download** (??) image link in zoomimg attribute?

Comment: yes ,  but the link in zoomimg attribute is not correct link(it can not be downloaded) , i think web site run some scripts to make correct link .